# Error C2064. I have tried everything I can think of to no prevail

Tags: c++

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

I have tried to check almost everything including double and int definitions but I keep getting this error. I checked other questions asked about this error but I couldn't find anything. If you guys could help me that would be great.

```
// Bonus.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

double Per_Pay(double L, double r, double m, double t);
double After_Pay(double L, double r, double m, double t, double k);

int main()
{
int L,m,t,k;
double r;
cout << "Please input the values of L (the loan amount), r (the doubleerest rate per     year),\nm (the number of paymenst in a year), t (how many years the loan is for), and\nk (the amount of payments that have been made).\n\n";
cin >> L >> r >> m >> t >> k;
cout << "The amount to be payed each time is $" << Per_Pay(L,r,m,t) << " and the amount to be payed after " << k << " amount of payments is $" << After_Pay(L,r,m,t,k) << endl;
return 0;
}

double Per_Pay(int L, double r, int m, int t)
{
double R,i;
i=(r/m);
R=(L*i)/(1-(pow((1+i),(-m*t))));
return R;
}

double After_Pay(int L, double r, int m, int t, int k)
{
double R,L_prime,i;
i=(r/m);
R=(L*i)/(1-(pow((1+i),(-m*t))));
L_prime=R((1-(pow((1+i),(-m*t))))/i);
return L_prime;
}
```

Comment: why are you surprised? you declare `R` as a `double` and then you try to use it as a function: `L_prime=R((1-(pow((1+i),(-m*t))))/i);`

Comment: All is well. Thank you all. I feel stupid but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
double R,L_prime,i;
//....
L_prime=R((1-(pow((1+i),(-m*t))))/i);
```

Let's trim it down even more:

```
double R, L_prime;
L_prime=R(whatever);
```

The problem is fairly obvious. `R` is a variable, not a function. What's more interesting is what you expect this code to do.

Comment: We took a test a couple days ago and I got the highest grade (86) but a lot of people failed and so the teacher is allowing us 10% extra back and we have to code this program from the book which is listed as an excercise. It gives us a formula and I tried to type it out.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I realize that I have to do R*(whatever). Wow I feel really stupid now but thank you!

Comment: @user2001659 oh, okay, I now see the confusion. In math that'd be an automatic multiplication, not in C++.